# Can I register a listener on MessageConsumer and then call the receive() method? (JMS)

Tags: java, concurrency, jms, listener, consumer

I was wondering whether I could register a listener on MessageConsumer and then call the receive() method. I know it doesn't sound like it is a practical scenario but it would be interesting to know. Does the JMS specification even allow something like that?

I know that Session is a single threaded context and the dispatch of messages by its listeners is going to be sequential but as I can imagine the thread that actually handles my registered listeners is going to do that and it has to be some thread that the JMS provider creates. That means that the thread that created the message consumer is separate and can concurrently listen for messages. Is what I just said right? What happens in that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know your scenario is not described in JMS specification. So it is left to JMS implementation. For example, in case of IBM MQ, a receive call after a message listener is attached would throw an exception with `MQRC_HCONN_ASYNC_ACTIVE` return code.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis of the threading problem is exactly where my thinking would go. I think you're in trouble due to 2 threads interacting with the one session.

OK, I looked it up in the JMS 1.1 spec. Two bits speak to this as I read it.

1. 4.5 - "A client may either synchronously receive a consumer’s messages or have the provider asynchronously deliver them as they arrive." Either/or, not both.
2. 4.4.6 - "It is erroneous for a client to use a thread of control to attempt to synchronously receive a message if there is already a client thread of control waiting to receive a message in the same session." I think that message listener is the other thread already waiting to receive on that same session.